# Title Tags are not Considered as H1

Tags: seo

My website Title Tags are not considered as H1 by most of the seo tool analyser. How to fix this issue.

here is the analysis URL [Site Checkup](http://seositecheckup.com/seo-audit/h1-and-h2-tag-test/myfitfuel.in)

Here is the URL of my website: [MyFitFuel](https://www.myfitfuel.in)

Answer (score 0):

Title tags and H1 are two separate entities so it sounds like everything is working as it should.

In fact here is some recent discussion on why title tag and H1 should be different.
[seomoz](https://moz.com/community/q/can-h1-and-meta-title-be-exactly-the-same-why-not)

Comment: @P082  if my answer worked for you or got you going in the right direction, please accept it so that I may get my reputation points, its been a while. Thanks :-)